# Upgrade to postgres96 on Alpine (/usr/bin/pg_dump: No such file or directory)

Tags: postgresql, alpine-linux, alpine-package-keeper

I'm trying to upgrade postgres locally so I don't get a version mismatch error.  This is what i do:

```
echo "http://dl-5.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories;
apk update

bash-4.3# apk add postgresql-dev
(1/4) Installing libressl2.4-libtls (2.4.4-r0)
(2/4) Installing libressl-dev (2.4.4-r0)
(3/4) Installing postgresql-libs (9.6.5-r0)
(4/4) Installing postgresql-dev (9.6.5-r0)
Executing busybox-1.24.2-r13.trigger
OK: 353 MiB in 108 packages
bash-4.3# pg_dump
bash: /usr/bin/pg_dump: No such file or directory
```

I'm at a loss - any idea what the problem is please?

Comment: That bash error shows it looking for a particular path to `pg_dump`, rather than searching through `$PATH`. Do you have a `pg_dump` alias or function defined? Try `'pg_dump'` with quotes.

Comment: Hi.  No there's no alias or function defined.  'pg_dump' results in the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess but I guess you've not installed postgresql. In order to use the pg_dump you must have installed this, or if you do have it already and I'm wrong try reinstalling it like so:

```
bash-4.3# apk del postgresql
(1/4) Purging postgresql (9.6.5-r0)
(2/4) Purging postgresql-client (9.6.5-r0)
(3/4) Purging libedit (20170329.3.1-r2)
(4/4) Purging libxml2 (2.9.4-r4)
Executing busybox-1.26.2-r5.trigger
OK: 37 MiB in 25 packages
bash-4.3# apk add postgresql
(1/4) Installing libedit (20170329.3.1-r2)
(2/4) Installing postgresql-client (9.6.5-r0)
(3/4) Installing libxml2 (2.9.4-r4)
(4/4) Installing postgresql (9.6.5-r0)
Executing busybox-1.26.2-r5.trigger
OK: 53 MiB in 29 packages
bash-4.3# pg_dump
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "root" failed: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
bash-4.3#
```

As you can see from above pg_dump is working because it is in the postgresql package even though as listed on alpine packages site it should be within the postgresql-client package as shown [here](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?branch=edge&name=postgresql-client&arch=x86_64&repo=main) but it doesn't work unless postgres is installed. If you can't have a full postgres installation, I recommend this workaround which is a bit unclean, install postgres, backup the pg_dump binary, uninstall postgres then restore pg_dump like so:

```
bash-4.3# apk add postgresql
(1/2) Installing libxml2 (2.9.4-r4)
(2/2) Installing postgresql (9.6.5-r0)
Executing busybox-1.26.2-r5.trigger
OK: 53 MiB in 29 packages
bash-4.3# cp /usr/bin/pg_dump /usr/bin/pg_dump
pg_dump     pg_dumpall  
bash-4.3# cp /usr/bin/pg_dump /usr/bin/pg_dump.back
bash-4.3# cp /usr/bin/pg_dumpall /usr/bin/pg_dumpall.back
bash-4.3# apk del postgresql
(1/2) Purging postgresql (9.6.5-r0)
(2/2) Purging libxml2 (2.9.4-r4)
Executing busybox-1.26.2-r5.trigger
OK: 38 MiB in 27 packages
bash-4.3# mv /usr/bin/pg_dump.back /usr/bin/pg_dump
bash-4.3# mv /usr/bin/pg_dumpall.back /usr/bin/pg_dumpall
bash-4.3# pg_dump
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "root" failed: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
bash-4.3#
```

It is not ideal but it has worked for me in the past

Comment: I did have postgresql package installed (one of those try again and it worked sort of things), points for the work around to get pg_dump.  Thanks